# how to send byte array to server in flash builder (Flex 4)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air, flash-builder

I have a video file in my local system.I am using windows XP in my system. Now i want to send this video file byte array to server in Flash Builder (Flex 4). I am using PHP at server end.

How can i do this? Please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.writeBytes() will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Via [this link:](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/archive/index.php3/t-216422.html)
.

```
// serialization
var serializedSound:ByteArray;

serializedSound = serializeSound(sound);
serializedSound.position = 0;

// unserialization
var newSound:Sound = new Sound();
newSound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, deserialize);
newSound.play();

function serializeSound(sound:Sound):ByteArray
{
var result:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

while( sound.extract(result, 8192) ){ 
result.position = result.length; 
}

return result;
}

function deserialize(e:SampleDataEvent):void
{
for ( var c:int=0; c<8192; c++ ) {
if(serializedSound.bytesAvailable < 2) break;
e.data.writeFloat(serializedSound.readFloat());
e.data.writeFloat(serializedSound.readFloat());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need just sending the bytearray to PHP or also getting the bytearray?

For sending the bytearray you can use Zend_AMF:
http://framework.zend.com/download/amf

It will handle all the conversion, and in php you will get the bytearray as a string through a variable (I use variable reference as: `&$file` to save some memory on calling of method)

Here is some code snippet it can help you:
[Sending ByteArray to Zend_Amf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585685/sending-bytearray-to-zend-amf)

For getting the ByteArray you can use the [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) load() method to get all the bytearray of a local file.

Comment: i want to write my local system video file to server. what should i do in flex 4 so i can able to do this.

Comment: i am doing this like below:                                        <fx:Declarations>
<s:HTTPService id="httpServiceFeedback" url="server php file url" fault="faultEvent(event)" result="serverResponse(event)" useProxy="false" method="POST"> 
<mx:request xmlns=""> 
<username>{byteArray}</username> 
</mx:request>         
</s:HTTPService> 
</fx:Declarations>                                                             but when i am using above code flashbuilder editor is showing warning "Data Binding will not be able to detet assignments to byteArray"   where i am doing wrong. Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do know that creating a ByteArray of the video in Flex is literally storing that video to memory right?  Any kind of large or uncompressed video would use an enormous amount of client side memory which could cause errors if Flash hits its memory limit.

I don't think you're going about this the right way.  What I recommend you do is instead just upload the video to the server which the server than then access the bytes within it.  If you want to upload the video to the server, look at this tutorial here which shows how to upload the file from Flex and a PHP script to get and store the file: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/17_Networking_and_communications_7.html#118972

From here, PHP could then access the bytes if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

AS3 Code:

```
uploadURL = new URLRequest();
uploadURL.url = "upload.php?fileName=videotrack";
uploadURL.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
uploadURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
uploadURL.data = rawBytes;
urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
urlLoader.load(uploadURL);
```

`rawBytes` is the byte array that you want to upload to the server.

PHP Code

```
$fileName = $_REQUEST['fileName'] . ".mp3";
$fp = fopen( $fileName, 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
fclose( $fp );
```

I've used a .mp3 extension because my byte array was data from a mp3 file, but you can set the extension to whatever type of file your byte array represents.